# Sphinxのsphinx-apidocコマンドによるソースドキュメント自動生成で、__init__関数を表示させる方法は？

Tags: python3, sphinx

Sphinxにおいて、docstirngを用いてソースコードからモジュールドキュメントを生成しています。

その際、sphinx-apidocコマンドを使用します。
例えば以下のように入力します。

```
sphinx-apidoc -f -P -o ./_documents_/Development/source/_root_source_ ./
```

このコマンドで生成された.rstファイルでは、モジュール名を除き一律に以下のような内容となります。

```
class\_API module
=================

.. automodule:: class_API
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
   :private-members:
```

__init__だけは特別に記載したい場合、以下の記述が必要ですが、sphinx-apidocコマンドで対応することはできるでしょうか？

```
   :special-members: __init__
```

Comment: この記事とかでしょうか？ [How to use Sphinx's autodoc to document a class's __init__(self) method?](https://newbedev.com/how-to-use-sphinx-s-autodoc-to-document-a-class-s-init-self-method), [sphinx-apidoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/ja/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) `警告 sphinx-apidoc はソースファイルを生成し、 sphinx.ext.autodoc を使って、見つけた全てのモジュールをドキュメント化します。`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sphinx-apidocコマンドでは指定出来ませんが、 `conf.py` に `autodoc_default_options` を指定する方法があります。

```
autodoc_default_options = {
    'special-members': '__init__',
}
```

公式ドキュメント:
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/ja/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_options

Comment: ありがとうございます。autodoc_default_options で__init__の書き出しに成功しました。ビルド結果と中間rstソースファイルを一旦削除してから実行したほうが良さそうです。最初はうまくいきませんでした。apidocの説明ページに環境変数SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONSを使用する記載もありました。こちらのconf.py記載のほうが手軽でよいですね。

Comment: 解決したようで良かったです